# how to make Gridview.Builder responsive

Tags: flutter, dart

hi guys I have a gridview.builder which looks good on some screen sizes but overflows on some screen sizes also.Please help I think I am lost. Im terrible with responsive designs lol so I will need some help explaining where I went wrong also.
here is the code:

```
GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: searchList.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                    mainAxisExtent:
                        deviceH < 827 ? deviceH / 3.1 : deviceH / 4.1,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
                      child: Material(
                        elevation: 8,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        child: Container(
                          height:
                              deviceH < 827 ? deviceH / 3.9 : deviceH / 4.1,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 2,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  child: AspectRatio(
                                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      //height: 85,
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      searchList[index].image,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 3),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                child: Text(
                                  searchList[index].header,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: AppStrings.fontName,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                    color: Color(0xff171717),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 1, left: 8, right: 3),
                                child: Text(
                                  searchList[index].text,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontFamily: AppStrings.fontName,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () async {
                                
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          bottom: 8.0,
                                          right: 8.0,
                                          left: 8.0),
                                      child: Container(
                                        margin:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                        height: 25,
                                        width: 162,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: AppColors.white,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                          border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                            width: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: const Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            'View group',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                color: AppColors.blue,
                                                fontFamily:
                                                    AppStrings.fontName),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }));
```

I would like for the card to look the same in all screen sizes.

Comment: wdym mean of look good, can you provide image, so we can compare betwen the screen size? because sometimes it depend on the ItemBuilder, and sometime the Gridview have been wrap with what widget. can you gave the overflow image too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative to not worrying about responsivity is to wrap your widget with Flexible(). You can just wrap your widget and define the max and min sizes of an item using SizedBox(). See an example below:

```html
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final gridItems = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('My Flex Grid View')),
      body: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: gridItems.length,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
          mainAxisSpacing: 16,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Flexible(
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Text(gridItems[index]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Flex Grid Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jgos.gif)